# Creating a row-wise average based off groups of variables in another column

Tags: r, grouping, mean

I am trying to create a new dataframe or columns with averages based off groupings in another column... this will be best explained with some examples:

[Data Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJdh4.png)

So in the data example I have Ports 1-5 and three variables (V2_IV, V3_IV, R2)
I would like to have an average for these variables for each hour that is based of groupings of ports.  Ports 1 and 2 as one average=a.  Ports 3, 4, and 5 as another average=b.

So to get something like this:
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgQcT.png)

*Note variable numbers given in results are just for example, not the accual averages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we recreate your data in R so we can work with it:

```
data <- data.frame(Year = 2014, Month = 8, Day = 26,
               Hour = c(9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11),
               Port = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
               DoY = 238,
               Date = "8/26/2014",
               Season = "Summer",
               V2_IV = c(19.361, 19.676, 21.831, 20.692, 19.405, 19.597, 19.8935, 22.5585, 21.321, 20.8605, 19.919, 20.4825, 23.401, 22.093, 21.7965),
               V3_IV = c(.872, NA, .826, NA, .868, .872, NA, .829, NA, .8665, .8715, NA, .8285, NA, .867),
               R2 = c(.998676, .998901, .9923, .994796, .992848, .997106, .996422, .972802, .995367, .996529, .995808, .998653, .988912, .996155, .987083))
```

The code below now assigns the ports to the groups that you mentioned. If you wish to scale this code to incorporate more groups then you can just assign more groups. The idea here is that you need a column that tells you what group each observation is assigned to. You provided two groups so I just used the binary assignment of an ifelse statement:

```
a <- c(1,2)
b <- c(3,4,5)

data$Group <- ifelse(data$Port %in% a, "a", "b")
```

Now we just need to calculate the averages for those three variables. You had some missing entries in the V3_IV column that I choose to input as NAs, in order to handle those missing values in the summarise_at function you have to specify `na.rm = TRUE` . If you fill in these values then that part is unnecessary.

```
library("dplyr")

avgs <- data %>% group_by(Group, Date, Hour) %>% 
  summarise_at(.vars = vars(V2_IV, V3_IV, R2), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time on this!  This should work for me.